# What is the fastest or usual way to calculate $(\frac{x-1}{2})^2$ mod $x$ if $x$ is odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Because:

A) for odd $x$ and $x \equiv 1\pmod {4}$  the upper formula is the same as $x - (x-1)/4$

B) for odd $x$ and $x  \equiv 3\pmod {4}$  the upper formula is the same as $(x + 1)/4$

Example A) ((17-1)/2)^2 mod 17 = 13 or 17-16/4=13 , 17 mod 4 = 1

Example B) ((19-1)/2)^2 mod 19 = 5 or (19+1)/4=5  , 19 mod 4 = 3

This question is closely connected with square residues or to be more precise with "centered" square residues! [reformulation of square residues for odd numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186758/reformulation-of-square-residues-for-odd-numbers) Example for 25:25-(25-1)/4 = 19

Comment: Should the title read "...mod 4 if x is odd?"

Comment: No.This is not the same!

Comment: It's not a matter of being appropriate or not, it's a matter of being comprehensible or not.

Comment: If $x\equiv 1\pmod 4$ then $({x-1\over2})^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and if  $x\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then $({x-1\over2})^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$ (in fact $({x-1\over2})^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$). However, how should $x+1\over 4$ be the same as $({x-1\over2})^2 \pmod 4$?

Comment: Please edit your problem then... it's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have made it clear you want to work $\pmod{x}$, then the expression is always $4^{-1}$ for odd $x$.

**Added**
Someone came along and added a very long explanation for a short computation I took for granted. Here is what I was thinking: Since $x=0\pmod{x}$,
$$((x-1)/2)^2=(-1/2)^2=1/4=4^{-1} \pmod{x}$$

You can easily compute what $4^{-1}$ is for your given $x$ with the Euclidean algorithm. Use the alg to find $a,b$ such that:

$$ax+4b=1$$

Then $4^{-1}=b\pmod{x}$

Comment: The point being that if $x = 2y+1$, $4 ((x-1)/2)^2 = (x-1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod x$.  If $x \equiv 3 \mod 4$, i.e. $x = 4j-1$ for some integer $j$, then $4j \equiv 1 \mod x$, so $4^{-1} \equiv j$.  If $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$, i.e. $x = 4j + 1$, then $4^{-1} \equiv -j \equiv 3j+1 \mod x$.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák I think I'm going to remove what you put because it's overcomplicated.

Comment: @rschwieb No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not if $x=1 \pmod 4$ then $0$, else $1$?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with the person's question being mod 4, and at the same time dividing by 4, which isn't invertible mod 4... do you have a sense for what he's asking?

Comment: This question is closely connected with square residues or to be more precise with centered square residues!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186758/reformulation-of-square-residues-for-odd-numbers. Example for 25:25-(25-1)/4 = 19

Comment: @rschwieb:  the question has changed (it is now $\pmod x$)